# Windows Error Messages Translations

Tags: delphi, winapi

My application requires some files to be present when being started.

I check those before Application.Initialize.

```
begin
  if not FileExists('required.db') then
  begin
    with Application do
    begin
      NormalizeTopMosts;
      MessageBox('Datei nicht gefunden' + ' (required.db)', 'Error', MB_OK); // Localize this
      RestoreTopMosts;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

The application should be localized for different languages. Once the application is started i do the translation with an database.

Howevever this file check has to be done before the appplication starts. 
So i now want to display the error message in the correct language.

In my example above i use:

```
MessageBox('Datei nicht gefunden' + ' (required.db)', 'Error', MB_OK); //Localize this
```

`Datei nicht gefunden` is the german translation for `File not found`.

I do not want to use resourcestrings or some file/db lookup for the translation.

On [this microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Emt.aspx) you can lookup the translations.

Becase the translations for those basic error messages are already stored in windows somewhere i want to use those.

So if the user has an english windows it should display `File not found` and so on.

The optimal solution would be:

```
MessageBox(GetTranslation(ERROR_FILENOTFOUND) + ' (required.db)', 'Error', MB_OK);
```

So my question is:

How can i get the Windows translation for basic error messages like "File not found" in the same language as the user OS?

Comment: The `FormatMessage()` function can provide localized strings for standard Windows error codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use [FormatMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: It would be easier to get error message with SysErrorMessage(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

Comment: Link-only answers are not great.

Comment: @J.Pelttari I went with SysErrorMessage but since you commented on this answer i'll leave the check :)